# HTML pop up works only when clicked every 2nd time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I new to the html and css. I am now learning about the pop up and have come across an issue.
Check out this simple fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/74agLucr/

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  opacity: 0;
  /* add this */
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

When you click on the text, the pop up shows up and disappears shortly. When clicked again, it will not do anything. I must click twice for it to pop up again. Could someone point me in the right direction and help me understand what is the issue?

Comment: Hey, your problem is, that with the class "show" is not removed when the popup blurs out with your animation. Therefore you have click twice till the class show is added again.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-fade-in-effect-using-pure-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the popup is that toggle adds a class if it isn't added and removes if already was added. That's why you have to click twice in order for it to work. You can try setting setTimeout() so it toggles off after 3 second animation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    if(!popup.classList.contains("show")){
  popup.classList.add("show");
  setTimeout(()=>{popup.classList.remove("show");}, 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for explaining. Your suggestion seems to mostly work but there is an issue. Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e3Lw89sd/. If you click again before the popup class remove timer has elapsed, you can mess up the pop up. For example, if you click it like 5 times in a row every 1 or 2 seconds it will start to get weird

Comment: Hi, I've just changed the solution, hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like exactly what I needed.